# Как отключить webdriver в FireFox через selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

options.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get("https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/chrome-headless-test.html")
```

Comment: В общем firefox с 88 вроде версии сломали это и оно больше не работает. Заменить?...ну наверное хромом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хочется FireFox, то придется брать старую версию браузера, получается версия 87. Можно обойтись [portable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./) (не забыв у него сразу выключить обновление), но тогда придется брать и старый geckodriver [версии 0.26](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) (в 0.27+ добавили какую то дополнительную проверку на то, что браузер установлен или что-то подобное). А это, в свою очередь, потребует отката до selenium 3.

Если же хочется selenium 4, то можно попробовать такие варианты:

1. В исходниках [geckodriver](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/testing/geckodriver/) (сама проверка происходит в [capabilities.rs](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/testing/geckodriver/src/capabilities.rs)) пытаться понять как он проверяет и выполнить условия.

(мне это не удалось. По коду он вроде бы (rust слишком инопланетный язык) читает ини-файл, которые есть в папке браузера, где он ищет, но не работает и все тут)

2. Собрать свой билд geckodriver

Для этого нужно.

- Выкачать [весь репо](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central) (как [zip](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/archive/tip.zip) ибо это mercurial).
- распаковать на реальный диск (это [важно](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/682) - без этого будет невнятная ошибка компиляции)
- поставить rust (у меня win 10 и я просто качнул официальный)
- поправить файл `testing/geckodriver/src/capabilities.rs` удалив проверку

  ```
   "binary" => {
       if let Some(binary) = value.as_str() {
           if !data.contains_key("androidPackage")
               && self.version(Some(Path::new(binary))).is_err()
           {
               return Err(WebDriverError::new(
                   ErrorStatus::InvalidArgument,
                   format!("{} is not a Firefox executable", &**key),
               ));
           }
       } else {
           return Err(WebDriverError::new(
               ErrorStatus::InvalidArgument,
               format!("{} is not a string", &**key),
           ));
       }
   }
  ```

чтобы осталось

```
  "binary" => {
  }
```

- [скомпилировать](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Building.html) (cargo вариант)

в папке `target` появится geckodriver.exe, который сможет запускать portable

Не знаю debug ли это версия - важно, что она работает. А под linux наверное нужно собирать в самом linux.