# Как зарегистрироваться в Гугл аккаунте, используя selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Моя задача очень проста в теории.
**Задача**: запускать и мониторить код в гугл колаб. Google Colab
Но, есть один нюанс, чтобы там что-то изменить, нужно зайти в гугл аккаунт.
Я попытался это сделать с chromedriver, не получилось.
selenium-stealth пробовал, что-то не получилось...
Сейчас пробую с geckodriver и firefox.
но ошибка повторяется.

**Ошибка в чем?**

Все дело в том что, как только было введен адрес почты, затем нажимается кнопка "Далее", затем нужно вводить пароль, но вместо него, там что-то типо такого "Этот браузер не является безопасным ...", тоесть срабатывает защита, детектор на бота.

Мой вопрос, как это исправить? И можно ли как-то по другому, без селениума?

Сам код, ниже:

```
url1 = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcolab.research.google.com%2Fdrive%2F..."
url2 = "https://colab.research.google.com/..."

from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
profile.update_preferences()

desired = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, desired_capabilities=desired)


driver.get(url1)
sleep(8)
email = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId')
email.send_keys("почта")

sleep(1)
nextBtn = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierNext')
nextBtn.click()

sleep(7)

passwd = driver.find_element('password')
passwd.send_keys("пароль")

nextBtn = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'passwordNext')
nextBtn.click()

sleep(400)
```

Пожалуйста, покажите как правильнее, или как можно это реализовать по другому, приму любые идеи.

Comment: Для начала - не файрфокс. В нем не работает "dom.webdriver.enabled" после 88 версии.

Comment: @vitidev хмм, понял, а не подскажите как это можно реализовать? ну или во вторых

Comment: Ну брать [старую версию фф](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1406222/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-webdriver-%d0%b2-firefox-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-selenium/1406643#1406643) или вообще хром. Но про это я ничего не скажу - хрома у меня нет.

Comment: @vitidev понятно, я вроде понял как этот детектор работает, почему-то мне кажется нужно отключить js-скрипты, и еще несколько хлама, ну посмотрю, получится или нет...

Comment: @vitidev думаю лучше буду использовать хром

Comment: Спасибо, уже не надо, я нашел способ!
Чуть позже сюда напишу, обязательно!